# How do I script out GRANT statements for an Oracle table using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

Does anyone know how to script out an Oracle table along with the GRANT statements in the script for
a table using Oracle SQL Developer 3.0?  I can't seem to get the GRANT's to come out.  This is what I did:

1. Right click on table
2. Choose Export 
   Export Wizard comes up.
3. Export DDL is checked
4. Export Data is unchecked
5. Grants is checked
6. click "Next" to proceed to create the script.

When the script is created, I don't the see the table permissions.

What am I missing?  I couldn't get this to work with an older ve

Comment: do you actually have them?

Comment: Maybe you could log in as `sys` and explicitly provide the grants via commands?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed.  DBA put me in the right role in order to script out this info.